# Can not bind to service's returned promise with Angular (ES2015)

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm learning to use Angular with ES2015 (using webpack) and while playing with the features I have encountered a problem. I can't seem to find what I'm missing so maybe one of you could direct me to the right direction.

Currently I'm simply trying to bind a controller to a service that returns mock data.

### Cat Service

<sub>catData.js just returns a mock array of cat objects</sub>

```
import {cats}  from './catsData.js';

export default class catService {
    getData() {
        return Promise.resolve(cats);
    }
}
```

### Cat Controller

```
export default class CatController {
    constructor(catService) {
        this._catService = catService;   
        this.cats = [];
        this.activate();
    }

    activate() {
        this.getData();
    }

    getData() {
        this._catService.getData().then(cats=> {this.cats= cats;});
    }

}
```

### app.js

<sub>Where I bootstrap it all</sub>

```
import angular from 'angular';
const app = angular.module('catApp', []);

import  catController  from './catController.js';
import  catService from './catService.js';

app
    .controller('catController', catController)
    .service('catService', catService);
```

### Simple test view

```html
<body ng-app="catApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="catController as vm>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cat in vm.cats">
                <div class="well">
                    {{cat.name}}
                    {{cat.age}}
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want to clarify that before I used `Promise.resolve` on my `catService`, I returned the data synchronically and everything worked. Now, the list of cats does not appear (No console error either)

Comment: Plunker or jsFiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after further digging I found that ES6 Promises do not play well with angular and used $q instead. This has fixed the issue:

```
import {cats}  from './catsData.js';

export default class catService {
  constructor($q) {
    this.$q = $q;
  }

  getData() {
      let defer = this.$q.defer();
      defer.resolve(cats);
      return defer.promise;
 }
}

catServoce.$inject = ['$q'];
```

Comment: For a little extra context, the main difference between `$q` and standard Promises is that `$q` kicks off the digest cycle when a promise resolves. This is why you tend to get weird issues when you use ES6 Promises in Angular; they kind of operate in a vaccum outside of Angular's change tracking. You can get around it somewhat by calling `$scope.apply()` whenever you resolve a ES6 promise, but I found it much easier to just stick to using `$q`, as you've done here.